# singleton beans concurrency in Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

Java Spring beans default scope is singleton. If we create a service (bean) with a class variable which may change in internal methods, This bean's usage of different threads may caused unexpected errors.So how to avoid this?

Comment: Well, dont do that. Make your beans stateless (or having only immutable state). Or make sure that all accesses to the mutable state is thread-safe.

Comment: How can i make beans stateless?

Comment: By not adding state to them. I.e. they should not have fields other than references to other beans, typically.

Comment: Ok. but if two threads run same method on a bean same time if there is a local variable inside method.it also give errors.it is hard to avoid keeping local variables.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Local variables are not shared between threads.

Comment: oh yes my bad they are on stack instead of heap.

Answer (score 1):

A Singleton pattern ensures there is only one instance of this class available to the JVM *(In case of Java you can have multiple instances per classloader/ in case of spring it per application context)*. This means that essentially need a global state into an application.

This is why we want the Singleton classes to be stateless, because if we any thread access it then we don't want internal variables to be mutated because of the lack of concurrency control.

In case you want to keep state you can later the scope of spring beans as per your requirement e.g request, prototype. These scopes will help serve the purpose to keep the state as per request/bean.

Comment: Actually a singleton, as in the singleton pattern, is a singleton per class loader NOT per JVM. In the Spring context it means a singleton per application context...